# How can I send multiple data in a MERN stack application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I need help to post multiple data on category and when I select multiple data on select input and submit it throws error. see below the error

```
  setSelected = (selected) => {
    this.setState({ selected });
  };
  handleSubmitPost = (e) => {
    const selected = this.state.selected;
    let select = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
      select = [...select, selected[i].value];
    }
    console.log(select);
    e.preventDefault();
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("title", this.state.title);
    fd.append("category", select);
    fd.append("article", this.state.article);
    fd.append("blogImage", this.state.blogImage);

    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:5000/posts`, fd)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

here is the model schema.
MODEL

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  category: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "PostCategory",
    },
  ],
  article: { type: String, required: true },
  blogImage: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

here is my route file.
ROUTES

```
router.post("/", upload.single("blogImage"), async (req, res) => {
  const { title, article, createdAt, category } = req.body;

  const newPost = new Post({
    title,
    category,
    article,
    createdAt,
    blogImage: req.file.path,
  });
  try {
    const savedPost = await newPost.save();
    res.json(savedPost);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});
```

when I select multiple on input select, this is the error when I submit.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

but when I select only one it passes. I can only save one in may category field, and I wanted to save multiple on my category field.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a 400 error. It looks like the axios post request is being made to http://localhost:5000/posts, however, it does not appear that there is a "/posts" route in your server code. Try changing your server code to accept a post request at "/posts." See below:

```
router.post("/", upload.single("blogImage"), async (req, res) => {

// vs 

router.post("/posts", upload.single("blogImage"), async (req, res) => {
```

Alternatively, you could drop the posts route from your axios request and make a request to http://localhost:5000.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment but still not working. however when I select one in my select input it passes, but when I select multiple in throws error.

Comment: by the way in my server.js I use this...

`const post = require("./routes/postRoutes");
app.use("/posts", post);`

Comment: `(2) ["5e9dd7509297c74bc86ae9cd", "5e9dd7569297c74bc86ae9ce"]`
`POST http://localhost:5000/posts/ 400 (Bad Request)`
`Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)`

Comment: I want to push the 2 data in my category